# sqldf is not null returns all rows

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a csv files containing a table with Accounts active and inactive, I'm filtering accounts on statecode because I only want to have accounts with status active in a new df. This works part works. The next thing I would like to do is create a new df which contains all accounts in which the column telephone1 contains data. What I tried is:

```
>df <- read.csv2("df.csv")
> df_active_accounts <- sqldf('Select * from df where statecode = 0')
> telephone1 <- sqldf('Select telephone1 from df_active_accounts where telephone1 is not null')
```

This piece of code returns the same amount of rows on the df_active_accounts as on telephone1. This leads to believe there are no rows which do not contain data. However I do see rows which do not contain data in the column. 
What am I doing wrong here?

[Column telephone1 has rows which do not contain data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSkN3.png)

Comment: Could you show the content of such a line  ?

Comment: Hi @MrSmithGoesToWashington, I have added a screenshot of the column telephone1.

Comment: But wa can't see if, for exemple, there is a blank character where there is no number .. could join a `dput` of a part of your data ?

Comment: The empty phone numbers are probably empty strings and not `NA`s. You can try: `telephone1 <- sqldf('Select telephone1 from df_active_accounts where telephone1 <> ""')`

Answer (score 0):

I was passing through the same problem and I solved it this way:

```
telephone1 <- sqldf("Select telephone1 from df_active_accounts where telephone1 <> 'null' ")
```